# Trying to view a MS PowerPoint 2010 file in a VS 2010 c# form

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I've spent three weeks googling it, and I -have- found snippets, but none of them have been useful. I'm trying to write a c# program that is able to view a powerpoint. I have no idea how. I've looked through SO many snippets and the MSDN pages in the Ppt interop and I'm completely at a loss. Has anybody done this, or knows how and would quickly demonstrate code showing me how to do this? As little code as needed to get it working would be preferrable. What I'm going for is this: A powerpoint slide is going to be displayed in a picturebox and every 40 seconds it's going to switch to the next slide. I am NOT allowed to export the powerpoints to pictures, and load the pictures (Which I couldn't figure out how to do, either). If anybodys wondering, yes this IS for a programming class, however it's not a graded assignment. I've spent three weeks on this and it's driving me insane. Any help at all would be appreciated. Thank you. If it helps, here's all the working code I've come up with on my own so far, and it's nothing like what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
        PowerPoint.Application oPPT;
    PowerPoint.Presentations objPresSet;

    const string strPres = @"E:\C#\Ch 16\PP Stuff\TestTextBox\TextBoxTestWithArrays\TextBoxTestWithArrays\Ad Analysis.pptx";
    const string myPath = @"E:\C#\Ch 16\PP Stuff\TestTextBox\TextBoxTestWithArrays\TextBoxTestWithArrays\";

{
        oPPT = new PowerPoint.Application();
        oPPT.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        objPresSet = oPPT.Presentations;
        objPresSet.Open(strPres, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

    /*
     * This crashes, and I'm clueless as to why it wouldn't work. I wanted it here
     * to check the # of msg boxes that opened against the # of slides in the ppt.
     */
        foreach (PowerPoint.Slides mySlides in objPresSet)
            MessageBox.Show("{0}", mySlides.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can we assume that MS powerpoint is installed on the same box where the c# program is running ?

Comment: Yes. Im using VS2010 and MS Office 2010 as well.

Comment: I need to view the powerpoint IN the form. The code I posted physically opens up powerpoint, which is not what I want. Thanks again to all of you who are browsing this and thinking of ways to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://skp.mvps.org/vb/pptvbwnd.htm
It explains how to display and control a presentation on form in VB5/6, but might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks. Looking now. Tbh, I'm not sure how helpful it'll be, as I don't know vb at all. I appreciate the link.

Comment: So, I've been looking through, and attempting to implement, the solutions you guys have posted. The VB stuff makes little sense to me and I'm not sure how to plug any of it into VS and get it to work, and ALL of the c# solutions aren't working for me. I downloaded that free activex controller and tried to work it into my C# form but it's telling me that:

Comment: You can't plug the VB code into VS directly.  MS tends to confuse the issue by calling them the same thing, but the version of VB in VS is very different from "classic" Visual Basic.  You' have to translate from VB into C# or whatever .NET language you prefer to use.  Mostly the code's just creating and manipulating a PowerPoint object and its properties/methods.

Comment: That's great to keep in mind. I had the chance to take a VB class, but chose c# because as I understand it, nobody really uses VB anymore (as far as finding a job is concerned). Thanks again.